# Implementing folder "hardlinks" on NTFS

Tags: filesystems, ntfs

So if you rename a folder target, and lets say you have a bunch of junctions pointing to it, those junctions break.

Hardlinks remedy this problem with files, but folders cannot be hardlinked. I hear hardlinks point to inodes is the reason they cannot be broken, because they are essentially pointers to the file's true identifier (the inode number) rather than just the file's assumed path.

What would be the easiest way to go about implementing or simulating "hardlinks for folders" in NTFS? If there is a way to do this in Linux, I'd also be interested in that (since I'm considering moving to a Linux filesystem if I can get this).

In a nutshell I wanna be able to rename a folder and have all junctions or symlinks targetting it use the folder's new name instead of breaking. I strongly prefer a way to do this on NTFS, but I'd entertain any other filesystems out there. Thanks

Edit: I'm not just looking for filesystems, I'm looking for any means necessary to accomplish this, whether it's filesystems that allow this, scripts, programs, practices, etc.

Edit #2: Doesn't have to be via hardlink

Comment: I know for a fact this will not be possible with NTFS, heck even some Linux distos [do not allow hard linking directories](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210741/why-are-hard-links-not-allowed-for-directories). I do not know which distros *do* allow directory hardlinks, if I did I would post it as an answer.

Comment: Doesn't have to be via hardlink. Can be via a script, program, etc that best solves the problem I'm having.

Comment: What I had in mind was a lookup table database that maps links and their inode targets (the links can't be broken when the program is first run) and a program that would make sure the links point to the inode and it's location when the program finishes, but this is a rather ugly solution, one to be avoided if possible.